# Write fluctuate coordinates to file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

From a mouse I have a command that looks like this:

```
movej([100, 200, 300, 1, 2, 1])= [X, Y, Z, RX, TX, RX].
```

The X Y and Z are varaibles and are not the same. They come out with 100 movej commands every second. If I use bufferwrite to write to a file, it only writes to last known command. I want to record like every command and write it to file (even if it is the same!). It should look like this:

```
movej([100, 200, 300, 1, 2, 1])= [X, Y, Z, RX, TX, RX]
movej .....
movej......
movej......
movej([120, 220, 330, 1, 2, 1])= [X, Y, Z, RX, TX, RX]
```

What do I have to change about the code?

```
    File file = new File("GcodeCoordinaten.txt");

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    fw.write(Gcode+"\n");
    fw.flush();
    //fw.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The command are coming from an mouseEvent and are formatted like this:

```
      Gcode = string.format( "movel(p[0.%d,-0.%d, 0.%d, -0.5121, -3.08, 0.0005])"+"\n", coX1, coY1, 150); .
```

2e EDIT

Hi guys, they way im buffering does work but for the application I use it doesnt work. I mean it doesnt have any effect on what I tried to do with it. The robot that executes these commands makes shockking movement. This is becuase to much commands are sended to it.

My problem seems more difficult then I think. Ive put in a method wich send coordinates over a TCP/IP port and also the previuous one to write to a file. As what I tried to do with writing to a file is to understand what has been sended to it. Ive been counter every single command thats been writed to the file and to the TCP port.

Both are writing simoustainly to the file and to the TCP port. The counter is increment by more then 3000 times per second! What causes this high increment?

The code looks like this:

```
         while(true){                   // true when mouse is connected                                                                     
         if (listen1.newdata = true){  // listener from the mouse/sensor 
                  coX1 += getX();
                  coY1 += getY();
                 bufferX = coX1;
                 bufferY = coY1;
                count++;
              }
              if(count == 100){
                 averageX = bufferX/100;
                 averageY = bufferY/100;
                 newdata = true;
                 coY1 = 0;
                 coX1 = 0;

                }
          if (newdata = true){
                 send(Gcode);         //This one sends to tcp/ip
                  write(Gcode;        // this one writes to file
                  counter++;          // This counter increments by more then 3000 p/s
                }
```

Input sensor: 100hz     (I cannot change the sample rate of the sensor!!)
Output command: it should be like 1hz with a maximum of 3hz
What is or could possibly made this counter increment so fast? Im out of ideas.

I just want that the program does not send or write so much commands.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here's that each time you want to write a new line to the file you create a new writer. You should create the writer only once then do the writing with that instance.

Compare these two codes and their output:
(Also use `FileWriter.newLine()` instead of "\n")
The good one:

```
    int i = 100;
    try {
        File file = new File("GcodeCoordinaten.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        while (i > 0) {
            fw.write("" + i + "\n");
            i--;
        }
        fw.flush();
        //fw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The bad one:

```
    int i = 100;
    while (i > 0) {
        try {
            File file = new File("GcodeCoordinaten.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            fw.write("" + i + "\n");
            fw.flush();
            //fw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i--;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. It did the job. But unfortuneatly it was not the right thing that I was expecting it from. The program is keep sending to much coordinates, even if it is buffered or the value has been changed,it is still sending the commands. Now I have to put some method in that says, if old coordinate equals new then do not send.